# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Posts::AddPost()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting an error message down below. I removed form to add values directly into MySQL, but no success. I also changed the date to varchar and counted all arguments many times. Inside the class, I'm fetching data successfully. Here is a piece of code.

Where is the issue? Thanks in advance.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Posts::AddPost(), 1 passed in C:....\OOP\posts.php on line 47 and exactly 10 expected in C:....\OOP\functions_oop.php:61 Stack trace: #0 C:....\OOP\posts.php(47): Posts->AddPost('1, 2 3, 4, 5, 6...') #1 {main} thrown in C:....\OOP\functions_oop.php on line 61

**functions.php**

```
public function AddPost($date, $title, $gallery, $website, $thumbnail, $categories, $tags, $model, $local, $status) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (post_date, post_title, post_gallery, post_website, post_thumbnail, post_categories, post_tags, post_model, post_local, post_status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$date, $title, $gallery, $website, $thumbnail, $categories, $tags, $model, $local, $status]);
```

**post.php**

```
$posts = new Posts();
$posts->AddPost("1, 2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$posts->AddPost( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10); // 10 arguments, 10 integers
```

and not

```
$posts->AddPost("1, 2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"); // 1 argument: a string
```